# C#: My Else statement gets caught up in the Array, how do I overlook it?

Tags: c#, list, if-statement

I am having trouble with this code, I want to have the code return an answer if the input matches an item in the list, (Can't use an array), or if there is no match, write the line *once* and repeat the code, but when I do this, the result is:

```
Please enter the type of gem you want on your wedding ring:
diamond
Im sorry that was not a valid selection.
Im sorry that was not a valid selection.
Im sorry that was not a valid selection.
Your wedding ring will feature your selection: diamond
Im sorry that was not a valid selection.
Im sorry that was not a valid selection.
```

The code is;

```
List<string> Gems = new List<string>();
Gems.Add("ruby");
Gems.Add("emerald");
Gems.Add("topaz");
Gems.Add("diamond");
Gems.Add("pearl");
Gems.Add("infinity stone");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the type of gem you want on your wedding ring: ");
string want = Console.ReadLine();
for (int g = 0; g < Gems.Count; g++)
{
    if (want == Gems[g])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your wedding ring will feature your selection: " + Gems[g]);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.");               
    }
}
```

Comment: [Step through you code in the debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method would be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote the `if - else` insde a loop,
so every time the loop start again one of them will happand

try this :

```
List<string> Gems = new List<string>();
Gems.Add("ruby");
Gems.Add("emerald");
Gems.Add("topaz");
Gems.Add("diamond");
Gems.Add("pearl");
Gems.Add("infinity stone");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the type of gem you want on your wedding ring: ");
string want = Console.ReadLine();
bool found = false;
for (int g = 0; g < Gems.Count & !found; g++)
{
    if (want == Gems[g])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your wedding ring will feature your selection: " + Gems[g]);
        found = true;
    }
}

if(!found)
    Console.WriteLine("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.");
```

or simply do this (recommended) :

```
List<string> Gems = new List<string>();
Gems.Add("ruby");
Gems.Add("emerald");
Gems.Add("topaz");
Gems.Add("diamond");
Gems.Add("pearl");
Gems.Add("infinity stone");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the type of gem you want on your wedding ring: ");
string want = Console.ReadLine();

if(Gems.Contains(want))
    Console.WriteLine("Your wedding ring will feature your selection: " + want);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.");
```

Comment: I appreciate this, I was able to work it with the first suggestion!  That addition you did, the bool value, that's a little new to me.  I'm not understanding how it works, with the first usage being found = true, and then the second usage being "if(!found)"  is this saying that the match alters the bool value to true, so it doesn't trigger the second if, but no match allows the second if to trigger?  Second confusion on my part, wouldn't !found = true since found was set as false?  Thanks if you have the time to discuss this!  :)

Comment: @Carter it works like this : if one of the values in the list is what you were looking for, than i'm saving it on the boolean variable, and then exiting the loop. affter the loop i'm checking if the value you were looking for was found (if the value of found is trure, it can only hapend if the if statement was entered, if it is false, the if statement were never entered) and respond accordinlly. if !found ==true it means found ==false, and the value were not found

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining that, that's a really cool method!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than looping through the list trying to find if it contains the `want` value manually, you can use one of the useful methods on the `List<T>` type such as [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string want = Console.ReadLine();
if (Gems.Contains(want))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your wedding ring will feature your selection: " + want);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.");               
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, only issue is Im learning about iteration and have to use it in the code.  But yours looks like what I'd be doing if I was just coding for myself!

Answer (score 1):

If you want use right tool for checking is value exists in the collection, then `HashSet<T>` will be that tool.

`HashSet<T>` was designed exactly for that reason. `Contains` will return `true/false` in one operation, where `List.Contains` will iterate through whole collection until value found.

In your case it will provide tiny tiny better performance

```
var gems = new HashSet<string>();
gems.Add('ruby');
gems.Add('diamond');

if (gems.Contains(want))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your wedding ring will feature your selection: {want}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.");
}
```

For iterating you can use LINQ approach for printing value only once

```
var gems = new List<string>
{
    "ruby",
    "emerald",
    // ...
}

var answer = 
    gems.Where(gem => gem == want)
        .Select(gem => $"Your wedding ring will feature your selection: {want}")
        .DefaultIfEmpty("Im sorry that was not a valid selection.")
        .First();

Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Comment: Whilst arguably a nice answer, I'm not sure LINQ is a good solution for novice programmers

Comment: Did you test this before posting? It outputs `System.Linq.Enumerable+<DefaultIfEmptyIterator>d__91`1[System.String]`. It's great to put alternative solutions, but make sure they work.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks, `.First()` were missing, fixed